# Permitted image formats on HTML pages

Tags: html, image, web, browser

Can someone please list all the image formats (.jpg, .png, .gif, etc.) that most modern browsers will accept and render?

Comment: I'll give you a full list. It's called GOOGLE

Answer (score 0):

Try this : comparison of browsers in wikipedia [Permitted images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support)